# Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<bankKonto> to boolean

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public ArrayList<bankKonto> getKonto() {
    return konto;
}
```

And when i am in my main i add bankKontoObject to make a new one. 
Then i add 3 to my bankKonto

when i try to do a for loop

```
for(bankKonto b; bankKontoObject.getKonto() {


    System.out.println(b.getNummer()  + " " +b.getSaldo());

    }
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: change to for(bankKonto b: bankKontoObject.getKonto())

Comment: Recheck the syntax for a Java `for-each` loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(bankKonto b : bankKontoObject.getKonto()) {
    System.out.println(b.getNummer()  + " " +b.getSaldo());
}
```

You missed a ')' at the end of 'getKonto' and the ';' should be a ':'

Comment: Omg.. Sorry guys and gals. (fml) Thanks!

Comment: No problem :)
Would be kind of you marking my answer as solution :)